Глючит клавиатура в Telegram Web App на IOS
Всем привет! На днях начали разрабатывать приложение на telegram web app и столкнолись с неожиданной проблемой, на IOS устройствах web app прячется за клавиатурой (прикрепил скрин с проблемой)
Хотя если открывать сайт в браузере то все работает корректно. Возникает вопрос, как с этим бороться?, я предполагаю что это проблема на стороне Telegram, но, возможно, ошибаюсь

Так глючит не клавиатура, а вебапп. Возможно потому что webview это не совсем сафари. Поскольку ни телеграм, ни webview вы починить не сможете, меняйте вёрстку.
